# Recording audio from microphone to file with AVAudioEngine

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, microphone, avaudioengine

I'm trying to implement simple recorder with AVAudioEngine.

I setup input and output nodes for audio engine, then create a file with path. After that, I install tap on inputNode and write buffers to file. The settings for installTap and file are from inputNode's input format for bus 0.

Everything looks fine, but the file I receive as a result contains only silence (is has correct duration, but no sound at all). 
What can be wrong?

My code:

```
private var engine: AVAudioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
private var file: AVAudioFile?

private func setupService() {
    if !accessWasGranted {
        print("No mic access")
        return
    }

    do {
        //I tried also to setup AVAudioSession, but this didn't help.
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord)
    } catch {
        print("Can't use this setting")
    }

    engine.connect(engine.inputNode, to: engine.outputNode, format: engine.inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0))

    let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("sound.caf")
    print(filename.absoluteString)
    file = try? AVAudioFile(forWriting: filename, settings: engine.inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0).settings)

    let format = engine.inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)        
    engine.inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: format) { (buffer, time) in
        print("Handle next buffer")
        do {
            try self.file?.write(from: buffer)
            print("Recording")
        } catch {
            print("Error writing to file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}

func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    return paths[0]
}

func startRecording() {
    if !accessWasGranted {
        print("No mic access")
        return
    }

    engine.prepare()
    do {
        try engine.start()
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func stopRecording() {
    if !accessWasGranted {
        print("No mic access")
        return
    }

    engine.stop()
    file = nil
}
```

In ViewController, I call setupService() in viewDidLoad() method, and then startRecording() and stopRecording() on buttons tap.

**UPD:** I also tried to use the default setup of input node + mixer, but the result is the same (silent audio).

```
private func setup() {
    let mixer = engine.mainMixerNode
    let mixFormat = mixer.outputFormat(forBus: 0)

    DocUtil.printDocPath()
    file = try? AVAudioFile(forWriting: DocUtil.docPath().appendingPathComponent("sound.caf"), settings: mixFormat.settings)

    mixer.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: mixFormat) { (buffer, time) in
        print("Received buffer: \(buffer)")

        do {
            try self.file?.write(from: buffer)
            print("Buffer saved to file")
        } catch {
            print(NSString(string: "Write failed"));
        }
    }
}

func start() {
    engine.prepare()
    do {
        try engine.start()
    }
    catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func stop() {
    engine.stop()
    file = nil
}
```

Comment: What is this line for? `engine.connect(engine.inputNode, to: engine.outputNode, format: engine.inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0))`

Comment: This is my attempt to create an active chain, but obviously it didn't work. It also doesn't work without any node connected, even though in WWDC it was mentioned that somehow it should be possible to just receive buffer from input node's tap (and input node supposed to be created automatically).

Comment: You should be able to just set a tap on the built-in mixer node (`mainMixerNode`). Everything is connected correctly by default. I don't know why you are making this extra connection or tapping the input node.

Comment: For now it doesn't look like it is connected correctly: I updated the question and posted the initial version of my audio service, where I use the default setup and have the same result with silent audio.

Comment: @Maria, did you find the solution for this??